# Line colour of 3D parametric curve in python's matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been googling quite some time with no success ... maybe my keywords are just lousy. Anyway, suppose I have three 1D `numpy.ndarray`s of the same length I'd like to plot them in 3D as a trajectory. Moreover, I'd like to be able to do either of the following things:

1. Change the colour of the line as a function of `z`
2. Change the colour of the line as a function of time (i.e. the index in the arrays)

[This demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/lines3d_demo.html) has an example of making such a curve:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
theta = np.linspace(-4 * np.pi, 4 * np.pi, 100)
z = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
r = z**2 + 1
x = r * np.sin(theta)
y = r * np.cos(theta)
ax.plot(x, y, z)

plt.show()
```

[image]

But how do I achieve `1` or `2`? Solutions to only one or the other are welcome!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As with normal 2d plots, you cannot have a gradient of color along an ordinary line.  However, you can do it with `scatter`:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
theta = np.linspace(-4 * np.pi, 4 * np.pi, 100)
z = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
r = z**2 + 1
x = r * np.sin(theta)
y = r * np.cos(theta)

#1 colored by value of `z`
ax.scatter(x, y, z, c = plt.cm.jet(z/max(z))) 

#2 colored by index (same in this example since z is a linspace too)
N = len(z)
ax.scatter(x, y, z, c = plt.cm.jet(np.linspace(0,1,N)))

plt.show()
```

---

I liked [@Junuxx's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1404505/junuxx) [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15617860/1730674) so I applied it here:

```
for i in xrange(N-1):
    ax.plot(x[i:i+2], y[i:i+2], z[i:i+2], color=plt.cm.jet(255*i/N))
```

[image: 2-Color by index]
[image: 2-Color lines by index]

Comment: I think the first statement isn't exactly correct, see my answer. But +1 for demonstration of jet colormap including normalization.

Comment: Well, it is technically true, hence you must plot `N` `line3D` objects, but your hack is pretty awesome :)

Comment: It seems like `int(255/N*i)` is required for the color spec. For me a float results in the max value for the colormap.

Comment: @gauteh `cm.jet` accepts a float from `0.0` to `1.0` or an int from `0` to `255`, so if you use a float greater than `1.0`, it will be interpreted as `1.0`.  So if you want to pass a float, just leave off the `255`: `plt.cm.jet(i/N)`.  For me, `N` and `i` are ints so I multiplied by `255`.

Comment: When I try using the hack for a 2D version of this scatter plot, I receive the following error :  `Invalid RGBA argument`. Does anyone know why?

Comment: I'm trying to iteratively add line plots to the same figure. Maybe this is the problem?

Answer (score 16):

You can plot every line segment separately, as shown below. This just loops over 6 predefined colors, since @askewchan's answer already demonstrates well how to use a colormap.

```
cols = 'rgbcmy'

for i in range(len(x)-1):
    ax.plot(x[i:i+2], y[i:i+2], z[i:i+2], color=cols[i%6])
```

[image]